# Website "gosugamers.net" is detecting Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

When you open website gosugamers.net, it shows the following,

[image]

After 5 seconds it automatically directs to the main page. But I tried to open it using selenium, it got stuck at the above screenshot.

Chrome Driver Version: 86

Things I tried so far,

1. Edited ChromeDriver.exe using VIM and changed the value of this

   var key = '$cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_'; Original Value

   var key = '$abc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_'; Updated Value
2. options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
   options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
3. 

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
```

Getting same results by using all above approaches.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: I think I have found the solution.

Comment: chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

Comment: I used above chrome options and it bypased the detection.